# How to get certain expected values using SOAP UI Xquery Matches

Tags: xquery, assert, soapui

I have a webService that returns certain values.  I know what those values will be.  I want to pick them out of the XML and if those values are true I want the assertion to pass.  Imagine that my test passes if I get this result...   How can I assert that that is the case?

```
     <BasicPersons>
           <id>4</id>
           <firstName>Patricia</firstName>
           <middleName>A</middleName>
           <lastName>Cluss</lastName>
        </BasicPersons>
        <BasicPersons>
           <id>5</id>
           <firstName>Benjamin</firstName>
           <middleName>L</middleName>
           <lastName>Handen</lastName>
        </BasicPersons>
        <BasicPersons>
           <id>6</id>
           <firstName>Ellen</firstName>
           <lastName>Frank</lastName>
        </BasicPersons>
        <BasicPersons>
```

Comment: More details please. I do not see any boolean values in there. When are they "true"? What kind of answer do you expect? Are you familiar with XQuery? Do you need to know how to execute XQuery, which programming language are you using?

Comment: That is the soap Response that I expect?

Answer (score 4):

SoapUI provides XPath assertion for test steps that extracts XML element from the response and compare it with expected data.

Let's take you XML fragment as an example (I added root element to make it well-formed). First create in SoapUI new `Test Request` step and fill it with request XML. Let's then check whether response contains BasicPersons element with id=4 and all other specified fields. Add new assertion `XPath Match` from `Property Content` group. Then type in the expression for the check. Here is what I get:

```
boolean(/root/BasicPersons[id=4 and firstName="Patricia" and middleName="A" and lastName="Cluss"])
```

`Expected Result` shall be `true` if XPath matches XML response. The assertion fails otherwise.

You may create several assertion for testing several persons from your response.

Comment: Sounds like it should work.   Only one way to find out though.

Answer (score 1):

A xpath expression like...

```
((//*:BasicPersons[1]/*:middleName)='A' and (//*:BasicPersons[1]/*:firstName)='Patricia') and so on for other fields)
```

This will return TRUE when all condition will match the response.

Comment: Please do not use signatures/taglines in your posts. Your user box counts as your signature, and you can use your profile to post any information about yourself you like. [FAQ on signatures/taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I am so used to that old school format of adding signature manually. Shall update now :)