# SoapUI query Match with multiple conditions

Tags: java, soap, soapui

I have this web service method:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.http.accede.sergas.es">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:validarLogin>
         <login></login>
         <password></password>
      </ws:validarLogin>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

which I want to mock using SOAPUI. I want to mock it so only user admin/admin should get an OK response and any other combination should bring an error.

I tried using Query Match like so:

```
//ws:validarLogin/login
```

which should be admin.

I also created condition:

```
//ws:validarLogin/password
```

which should be admin too.

But this results in *any* of those conditions returning OK while I need only for my mock to return true when BOTH of params are "admin". How can I specify this "AND" condition?

Comment: You should modify your service implementation, so you can deal with the params sended by the query,

Comment: I have no control over my service (it was made by someone else); my service works fine, what I want to modify is the *mock's* behavior

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get certain expected values using SOAP UI Xquery Matches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13611683/how-to-get-certain-expected-values-using-soap-ui-xquery-matches)

Answer (score 1):

```
//ws:validarLogin[password='admin']/login
```

Comment: Could you elaborate little more

Answer (score 1):

A XPath expression as below may help you out

```
((//ws:validarLogin/login)='admin' and (//ws:validarLogin/password)='admin')
```

Expected Value:

```
true
```

Answer (score -1):

You can concatenate both parameters and compare to the given string.

XPath:

```
concat(//ws:validarLogin/login, '.', //ws:validarLogin/password)
```

Expected Value:

```
admin.admin
```